# If you raise the price of your iPhone app do the old users have to pay to upgrade?

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

We're considering doing some experimentation with the price point on our iPhone app and I just want to make sure that if we raise the price we won't get a flood of user complaints that apple is charging them the price difference to upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the don't pay the upgrade. In fact, it is an interesting way to launch your app: a small price at the beginning, as a special promotion, and then increase it if you made significant improvements.

Google "iphone app pricing strategies" for info on how other apps did in the store.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's a way to encourage your potential users to buy it ASAP.